# Oracle Apex function

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

Need quick help When i run this function i do not get the value i need, but when i run the select query separately i get the result i want

for example when i put clid = 108xxx i should get subid = 356xxx

```
create or replace FUNCTION get_subid(clid IN NUMBER ) 
   RETURN NUMBER
   AS subid NUMBER;
   BEGIN 
      for c1 in (SELECT SUBJECTID
                  FROM "SubjectXClient"
                  WHERE CLID = clid
                  order by SUBJECTID desc) loop
          subid := c1.SUBJECTID;
          exit;
      end loop;    
      RETURN subid ;
   END ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that your WHERE clause is ignoring the parameter to the function because it has the exact same name as the column.  Rename the parameter and try it again.

Comment: Your guess was right, i changed the parameter and it resolved the issue.